# How to generate random integers which are multiples of 30 in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, random

I'm trying to generate random integers that are are multiples of 30  in JavaScript.

That is:

```
0 60 0 180 120 ...... and so on 
in range between 0 to 360 for example
```

So I am looking for a function something like this:

```
function (_range,_multi)
{
   Math.round(...);
   return rndNum;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a live demo that shows a full working function - the general idea is that you multiply by (max/multiple), floor the value, then multiply it by the multiple:

```js
function generate(min, max, multiple) {
    var res = Math.floor(Math.random() * ((max - min) / multiple)) * multiple + min;
    return res;
}

alert(generate(0,  360, 30));
```

Comment: What about the `min` param?

Comment: @OriDrori Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Generate a random number between 0 and 12 (range) and multiply by 30 (multi):

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 12) * 30
```

This gives you `[0, 360)` (so you never get 360)

Answer (score 1):

Seems like that should work.

```
function randomMultiple(max, mult) {
   return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max / mult)) * mult;
}
```

Thus a call of `randomMultiple(360, 30)` would produce an element of `G` with

```
G = { y = 30 * x | 0 < x < 12 }
```